# Regex: Matching a pattern but excluding part of the pattern

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to figure out how to exclude my match from the following sample:

```
myJavascriptArray(["foo","bar"]);
```

I can match the string no problem with:

```
myJavascriptArray\(.+\);
```

Really, all I want is the `["foo","bar"]` part.

I can ignore the `myJavascriptArray` part using:

```
(?!myJavascriptArray)\(.+\);  // matches (["foo","bar"]);
```

But then I'm completely lost!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
string.match( /myJavascriptArray\((.+?)\)/ )[1];
```

Or to safeguard:

```
var m = string.match( /myJavascriptArray\((.+?)\)/ );
var myval = m ? m[1] : "";
```

This capturing the interested value in a group and use that group in output array.

Comment: I should have said - I'm not actually going to be using javascript, it will be Ruby but the match looks like it works thank you so much.

Comment: Yes similar concept works for ruby or or any other language also.